# Having problems installing.....GUI or anything else...on an HP BL680c running 18.04

Tags: server, package-management

So far I have Ubuntu 18.04 installed on my offline server (phone is my only internet access, which will not share its connection with other devices).  I have mounted a USB flash drive to transfer "contents", deb packages, and releases to a /home/repository/dists...... directory structure.  This allowed apt to update, and start functioning on some level, but that seems to be it.  Even with sources.list modified to include the local repository, and the deb packages for tasksel copied into the repository, it still crashes with error messages about not finding the deb packages for laptop_detect, tasksel, and tasksel-data at the www address for the ubuntu archive.  Attempting "sudo apt install Ubuntu" for the GUI fails similarly

Do I really need to download/replicate the 100+Gig archive in its entirety for all this to work smoothly?  If not, help in creating the right structure and content in my local repository for tasksel, and eventually the Ubuntu GUI to install correctly greatly appreciated.

Jon W.

(P.s. added with edit)

Part of my confusion stems from this being my first practical excuse for "learning all about servers", first experience with linux, and that I have a "non-standard" application for this server (offline processing power for financial/economic modelling).   Remaining offline is a survival strategy/imperative for when the output of said modelling might start pissing certain influential parties off.  All that I have done so far was on the basis of how-to instructions that did not clearly differentiate between what would allow apt to function and find everything it needs for itself, or finding everything it needs to install tasksel and/or everything else.  Im just trying to get to where, with a GUI, the system is as ready and user friendly as possible for undertaking the acquiring and installing what is needed for the applied modelling purpose.  This will include R, some sort of spreadsheet app, statistical software of various types...generally like that.  This might effect, for example, the main question of whether or not downloading the whole archive might be advisable or not.  Since nobody I have access to can hot plug an SAS drive into their system,  getting a compatible HD and downloading the whole archive onto it remotely is something I would prefer to delay.  If thats just how it is, though, I could just bite that bullet now if necessary.