# Weird display boot up problem with output writing over my command line

Tags: command-line

I've got 18.04 installed on my offline HP Blade server, and have been thrashing about since then trying to install a GUI and other things requiring a local repository etc. I have [another question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1249338/having-problems-installing-gui-or-anything-else-on-an-hp-bl680c-running-18) posted about all that.

While that has been stumbling, forward I have acquired this other problem, where by the time the enclosure, server, and Ubuntu have booted to command line login prompt, there's this monitor detect error (only monitor involved still working fine) whose syntax is like the following:

- First on every line a number like this:

  ```
  [1234.123456]
  ```
- Then another bracketed entity like this:

  ```
  (drm:radeon *error* vga-1 :probed a monitor but no|invalid EDID)
  ```

I can't swear that's verbatim, but close. These lines continue to display, one after another, with the `[1234.123456]` numbers to the left ascending in order, writing over into the middle of what I'm trying to type at the command prompt. This doesn't affect what I'm typing though. Even with all the characters inserted in my attempt as, for example, at:

```
sudo apt-get upd[1234.123456][....]ate
```

or similar, the commands still work. The inserted or pasted over characters are ignored when you hit <kbd>Return</kbd>. It is annoying though.

Thoughts on getting rid of this?

Answer (score 0):

It's a persistent error, for example on the Raspberry Pi, if you undervolt it, it will do the same thing as you get there. I suggest google the error or wait until someone else has an idea here.

Also unplug monitor vga-1 and change cable. It might be broken.

Comment: OK!  That makes sense.  I have this HP C7000 enclosure with a 4 processor blade in it.  There are slots for 6 ps, but I have only 2, these plugged into a large UPS, then into the wall in my 100yo apt.  Low voltage you say?  Does it go away when voltage goes back to normal?  As for VGA-1, there is none.  I have a ViewSonic monitor plugged into the "SUV" cable that plugs into the front of the server.  There are no other vga/svga/hdmi outlets.

Comment: That was an example with the under-voltage! The problem is the cable/slot VGA!

Comment: I found a solution.  It may cause a replacement monitor not to work when first plugged in, but you can turn off the EDID scan at boot.  No more [1234.123456](probed monitor, but no EDID)×1000.